# Sharepoint custom field type. Get current list item id

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I am creating custom field type. I want to view a attachments when list item in display mode so:

create class:

```
public class Kolumna: SPFieldText
    {
        public Kolumna(SPFieldCollection field, string fName) 
            : base (field, fName)
        {   
            int fakeItemId =1;

            SPFolder folder = field.Web.Folders["Lists"].SubFolders[field.List.Title].SubFolders["Attachments"].SubFolders[fakeItemId];

            foreach (SPFile item in folder.Files)
            {
              // todo add to column value (?)
            }
        }
```

any idea how get current ListItem Id? And did you know whitch metod is run when sharepoint form get colum value? I try override GetFieldValueAsText and GetFieldValueAsHtml but no effect :/

Answer (score 1):

Use like this :

```
  ((YourCustomFieldControlClassType)this.FieldRenderingControl).ListItem
```

to access the `listitem` inside the Custom `FieldType` class to access the current listitem which is getting processed.

Cheers!!

Sangeet Ahuja (www.sangeetahuja.com)

Answer (score 0):

`public override object GetFieldValue(string value)` is called to retrieve the value of the custom field type.

Comment: yes but it fire when sharepoint get value to List View. I need method which is run when we click in list element (display form).